# In which episode does Saeko ask Ryo out?

Tags: city-hunter

In the anime City Hunter, I am trying to find the episode where Saeko asks Ryo to go out with her. But when they arrived at the hotel she told him to go and had a waiter hand him a note, telling him to wait for her outside. After that, she is taken to a huge ship; while this occurs, Ryo follows her.

Answer (score 2):

You might looking for City hunter 2 episode 30 ("Ryo, Please Be Deceived: Present to a girl from Saeko")

I Hope this is the episode you looking for.

EDIT : I have removed video link as it was not legal to add it in comment.

Comment: Welcome to the Anime & Manga SE. Please don't post links to illegal streaming sites in answers; see for instance [this post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/635/2604).

Comment: @Maroon : I will take care of that next time. Thank you.

Comment: @afham : I think i have answered you question correctly , can you accept it ? or let me know if anything still missing.